# Is this the desired result of the algorithm for detecting incorrectly formatted code?

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

I think I have a case where the algorithm for detecting incorrectly formatted code isn't producing the desired result. I could be wrong, or this could be a non-fixable issue. Here's what happened:

I tried to post the following (but not within blockquotes):

> | recordid_parent | recordid | color | flavor | price | ingredients | tags |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | null | 1 | pink | strawberry | null | {...} | {...} |
> | null | 3 | green | pancake | null | {...} | {...} |
> | null | 5 | red | pumpkin spice | 3 | {...} | {...} |

to create a table. However, I got an error when trying to post telling me that my code was not formatted correctly. Removing all instances of "{...}" removed the error.